# ggplot: position_dodge results in overlap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following workflow:

```
rm(list=ls())

data(mtcars)
attach(mtcars)

library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(lazyeval)

my_func <- function(x, y) {
  test<<-mtcars %>% group_by_(x, y) %>%
    summarise(Freq = n()) %>% 
    mutate(Freq = Freq/sum(Freq))
  test
  } 
my_func('gear', 'cyl')

ggplot(test, aes(x=gear, y=Freq))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=cyl), position=position_dodge(width=0.1))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits = c(0,1))
```

However, the resulting plot does not show the bars next to one another, but rather some on top of one another. What gives and how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to make your minimal reproducible example _minimal_: only the processed dataset and plotting function matter here.

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean?

Comment: Don't import packages you aren't using or build a function when you can just process the data directly in your example. Keep it simple so it's as obvious as possible what's going on.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Can you show me how to build a function using what @Psidom provided below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the `cyl` column to factor.

```
test$cyl <- as.factor(test$cyl)
ggplot(test, aes(x=gear, y=Freq))+
       geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=cyl), position=position_dodge(width=1))+
       scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits = c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: How would you build a function to plot this? I am struggling with the variable substitution on this.

Comment: What kind of function are you looking for? Fyi, if you are talking about passing variable names, try `aes_string(x = "gear", y = var)` instead of `aes()`.

Comment: I was hoping the following would work, but apparently does not:

my_graph <- function(var1, var2) {
  ggplot(test, aes(x=var1, y=Freq))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill=var2), position=position_dodge(width=1))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits = c(0,1))
}
my_graph(gear, cyl)

Comment: As I mentioned, use `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`. So it can be `my_graph <- function(var1, var2) { ggplot(test, aes_string(x=var1, y="Freq"))+ geom_bar(stat="identity", aes_string(fill=var2), position=position_dodge(width=1))+ scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits = c(0,1)) } my_graph(gear, cyl)`. Call it like this. `my_graph("gear", "cyl")`.

Comment: I wish I could hug you!